# form is invalid while click on reset button

Tags: angular

I have 3 mandatory dropdown fields.while i reset the form all get cleared,but getting red border since it is invalid.

```
 resetSearch() {
    this.submitClickedMain = true;
   
    this.searchForm.reset();
   
    this.searchForm.get('type').updateValueAndValidity();

    this.searchForm.clearValidators();
    this.searchForm.setValidators(null);
    this.searchForm.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
```

I need to remove the red border on click reset button.and on submit button it should display the red border if it is not selected.

Comment: Can you share HTML and CSS snippets? Just want to check which classes are you using to highlight elements with red border.

Comment: <div class="form-group col-5" [ngClass]="{'e-error': type.invalid && (type.dirty || type.touched || submitClickedMain)}">
            <ejs-dropdownlist
            formControlName="type"
           [dataSource]='typeList'
           [allowFiltering]="true"
           [fields]="{text: 'text', value: 'value' }"
           placeholder="Type"
           floatLabelType='Auto'
           cssClass=' e-filled'>
       </ejs-dropdownlist>
       <sup class="text-danger">*</sup>

Comment: Try ` [ngClass]="{'e-error': type.dirty && !type.untouched}"`

Answer (score 0):

I think we should see how the red border gets defined for your dropdowns.

But my suggestion would be to check whether your formcontrol is dirty or not.

Reset will set dirty to false but set your invalid flag true.

So with something like this the red border can be removed after reset:

```
[class.error]="form.controls.yourControl.dirty && form.controls.yourControl.invalid"
```

For submit to add back red border with such a solution is to set your fields dirty:

```
this.form.controls.yourControl.markAsDirty();
```